# Get python ggplot bar axis right?

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I want to plot the results of throwing a dice in a bar chart using ggplot.

```
import numpy
import ggplot
import pandas

frame = pandas.DataFrame()

for i in range(6):
    frame.loc[i, 'pips'] = i+1

rand = numpy.random.random_integers(1, 6, 100)

for i in range(len(count)):
    frame.loc[i, 'events'] = numpy.sum(rand == i+1)

frame['propability'] = frame.events / frame.events.sum()

ggplot.ggplot(ggplot.aes(x='pips', weight='events'), frame) + ggplot.geom_bar()
```

The outcome is [image: this plot]

From the examples I expected the plot to

1. Have more width on each bar
2. Not have x=7 with no bar

**How do I fix these two things?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameters "binwidth", "limits" and "breaks" like this :

```
 ggplot.ggplot(ggplot.aes(x='pips', weight='events'), frame) +
 ggplot.geom_bar(binwidth=1) +
 ggplot.scale_x_continuous(limits = (1,6), breaks = range(1,7))
```

Which gives me :

[image: Histogram]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For `python3` I was required to change `xrange(1, 7)` to `range(1, 7)`.